# Como ordenar una columna de un dataframe por criterios especificos

Tags: python, pandas

estoy tratando de ordenar por moneda de la siguiente forma: Dolar, Euro, libra  y el resto en orden alfabético pero lo unico que he logrado es ordenarlo por orden alfabetico me falta la primera mitad.

```
Country     Currency
--------------------
Islandia     Euro
dinamarca   Euro
Colombia    Peso
Venezuela   Bolivar
USA         Dolar
UK          Libra
```

Ese seria el dataframe lo que desearia seria que quedará algo asi

```
Country     Currency
--------------------
USA         Dolar 
dinamarca   Euro
UK          Libra
Venezuela   Bolivar
Colombia    Peso
```

Cualquier idea es muy apreciada, gracias

Comment: Hola, ¿qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la función `sorted()` estándar de Python, si pones `sorted(lista, key=myfunc)` lo que hará python es llamar a la función `myfunc()` para cada uno de los elementos de la lista. Lo que retorne esa función será lo que se usará para ordenar, en lugar de los valores originales.

Así pues, si estuviéramos trabajando con una lista python "normal", como la siguiente:

```
monedas = ['Euro', 'Euro', 'Peso', 'Bolivar', 'Dolar', 'Libra']
```

podríamos crear una función `myfunc()` que recibiría el nombre de una de esas monedas, y devolvería un nuevo valor (que puede ser una nueva cadena) y sería esa nueva cadena la que python usaría para la ordenación. Así pues podemos por ejemplo anteponer un "0" delante de los nombres de monedas que quieras que aparezcan en primer lugar.

```
def myfunc(curr):
  if curr in ("Dolar", "Euro", "Libra"):
    return "0"+curr
  else:
    return curr
```

Y entonces las ordenaríamos así:

```
>>> sorted(monedas, key=myfunc)
['Dolar', 'Euro', 'Euro', 'Libra', 'Bolivar', 'Peso']
```

Fijate cómo han quedado las primeras las que te interesaban, y cómo aparecen sin el "0" delante. Sorted sólo usa lo que devuelve `key` para hacer la ordenación, pero los valores finales son los originales.

### Y en pandas?

El método de pandas para ordenar un dataframe se llama `.sort_values()`  y espera como primer parámetro el nombre de la columna que se usará para ordenar. Esta función también admite, como `sorted()`, un parámetro opcional `key=` que ha de ser una función (o una lambda). Su misión es similar al parámetro `key=` de la función python `sorted()`, pero con una diferencia muy importante. En Pandas lo que se le va a pasar a `myfunc()` no son valores individuales, sino **una columna completa** (un objeto de tipo `pandas.Series`. La misión de esa función es devolver esa columna "transformada".

Por ejemplo, en tu dataframe de ejemplo, la función que le pasemos a `key` recibirá como parámetro la columna con toda la lista de divisas. Deberá devolver otra Serie en la que cada elemento se cambió por otro valor. Por ejemplo, podemos usar el mismo truco de poner un "0" delante de las que queremos en primer lugar.

De hecho, la misma función `myfunc()` que habíamos escrito aquí serviría, si la aplicamos a la columna que recibirá `key`. Por tanto una sencilla lambda nos resuelve el problema:

```
>>> print(df)
     Country Currency
0   Islandia     Euro
1  dinamarca     Euro
2   Colombia     Peso
3  Venezuela  Bolivar
4        USA    Dolar
5         UK    Libra

>>> df = df.sort_values(by="Currency", key=lambda x: x.apply(myfunc))
>>> print(df)
     Country Currency
4        USA    Dolar
0   Islandia     Euro
1  dinamarca     Euro
5         UK    Libra
3  Venezuela  Bolivar
2   Colombia     Peso
```

Comment: Todo el proceso que acabas de mostrar me funcionó muy bien!
Muchas Gracias!